# Are there any good sources for already made KML?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I've been playing with some mapping and visualizing data. One problem that I'm running into though is that I don't have a lot of the polygon data for various regions I'd like to map. I have SOME kml for some of the points, but I need many many more. Ideally, if I could, I'd love to get kml files for every city within a state so that I can display them a county at a time.

Does anyone where a nice open source of KML data? I had a slight hope that google might provide them from some obscure path, but haven't had any luck. I was also hoping that it might be available through US Census data, but digging through there for anything is always a challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one source of KMZ files: http://www.gadm.org/.

Another source of data is the [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) which is available from [FusionTables](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=163505)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of KML data files created from US Census data.

Here is the direct source of census both in KML and shape files. For example this site has comprehensive road data for US: http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/

Note the KML (a newly available data format) is only from the 2010 Census, but the shape file data is extensive for years 2006-2013.

Also, here's a free collection of [KML based on US Census Data](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/census-data-in-google-earth/) showing various stats (e.g. population density, median age, etc.) on state-level and county-level.